# Does T-SQL or SSMS have a way to pre-define column display names?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

We've migrated to a SAAS platform from a 40-year-old mainframe system. Not all of the 40 years of data has been moved into the new system. For archival purposes, we've placed all 40 years of data into a SSMS database. Tables in the archive use the FIVE CHARACTER(!) column names from the mainframe. A data dictionary on the mainframe was used for name translations.

The data dictionary has also been moved to the SSMS archive. Unfortunately, I cannot find an easy way to translate mainframe column names into display names in reports without using "AS".

Is there any way to define the tables so that column names will be translated on reports without using "AS {display name}" for every single column?

Comment: How about creating views that have the column names you want.

Comment: FYI SSMS doesn't have *any* databases, it's just an IDE(like) application. It's the data engine (SQL Server?) that had the databases.

Comment: I would query the dictionary table to generate a bunch of column rename operations using sp_rename, then run it

Comment: Or, combining Scott's and George's suggestions, use _dynamic SQL_ to create `view`s of the tables based on the data dictionary column name translations. Hopefully 40-year old definitions are pretty static at this point so you won't need to update the view definitions frequently.